# Customise OverflowMenu Android with no divider and different position

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-menu, overflow-menu

I am trying to customize action bar overflow menu with no dividers and also it should come at the top. I tried all styles with

`parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow"`

and

`parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"`
 but nothing worked. Does anybody know how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: If you use a `ToolBar` you'l get the overflow menu just like the image

Comment: thank you man ...its a great help..i am trying out that ...it should work...thanks